# How do I clean the aerator or replace the head of my kitchen sprayer?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

How do I clean the aerator or replace the head of my CFG kitchen pull-down sprayer?

It swivels from left to right for either spray or flow - I know it detaches just cannot figure out how to clean or replace the head

Comment: We're going to need a lot more details, including the specific model. In general, many aerators just unscrew from the faucet, either from the inside, using a coin or screwdriver, or the outside, using pliers with rubber pads or a thick cloth/rag.

Comment: If the issue is mineral build-up, soaking the end in vinegar or CLR (a product sold to clean calcium, lime and rust  residue)